# visual C# is it possible to have more feedback than a progress bar for a process running?

Tags: c#, user-interface, process, backgroundworker

I'm developping an app in C# using microsoft visual studio (windows form).
What i want to do is to manage different environment through one GUI.

Thus, my gui have to start asynchronously some process (which are commandline applications).
The problem is that I can get the standard output of the process only once it's finished, meaning I can't show what the process is doing in runtime.
since the applications I want to run can take quite a long runtime (uploading big files ...) i would like to display the process output in runtime.

Thus, i created a backgroundworker to separate my gui from the process, and i tried to use a temporary file where the process output is written.
then using a FileSystemWatcher, I could use the "change" event to display the messages in my GUI.

My problem is that since the temporary file is open for writting, i can't read from it at the same time.
Here is my code, does anyone have a way to bypass this problem ? or an other way to do it ?

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Boolean done = false;
    private FileSystemWatcher observateur;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // delete the temporary file if existing
        if (System.IO.File.Exists("C:\\testoutput.txt"))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete("C:\\testoutput.txt");
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException exept)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exept.Message);
                return;
            }
        }
        File.Create("C:\\testoutput.txt");

        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                (backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        observateur = new FileSystemWatcher();
        observateur.Filter = "C:\\testoutput.txt";  
        observateur.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.OnChanged);
        observateur.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(this.OnCreate);
    }

    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        // I tried to bypass the problem of having the file opened by copying it but i doesn't work
        File.Copy("C:\\testouput.txt", "C:\\TEMP.txt", true);
    }

    private void OnCreate(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Created");
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string outputworker = "";
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(outputworker);

        while (!done)
        {
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\TEMP.txt");
            Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        outputTextArea.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
    }



    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] args = { "/k " };
        string outputWork = e.Argument as string;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10);

        System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\XXXXXXXXXX";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        int nArgs = args.Length;
        if (nArgs > 0)
        {
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < nArgs; i++)
        {
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Concat(process.StartInfo.Arguments, " && ", args[i]);
        }
        process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(20);
        process.Start();


        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(40);
        System.IO.StreamWriter sIn = process.StandardInput;

        sIn.WriteLine("ExternalCommandLineApp1.exe >> C:\\testoutput.txt");
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(60);
        sIn.WriteLine("ExternalCommandLineApp1.exe >> C:\\testoutput.txt");

        System.IO.StreamReader sOut = process.StandardOutput;
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(90);

        sIn.WriteLine("EXIT");

        outputWork = sOut.ReadToEnd();

        process.Close();
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);

        e.Result = outputWork;
        done = true;
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string output = e.Result as string;
        //outputTextArea.Text = output;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using actual IPC techniques instead of a file.

Comment: Thanks, but since i'm quite new to C#, do you have any exemple or good website which explain how to program an IPC ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=inter-process%20communication%20c%23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way with what you've already got is to exploit the `UserState` you can pass with the `BackgroundWorker`.

In the `backgroundWorker1_DoWork` method, you can use

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, "Whatever text you want to send right now.");
```

And in `backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged`, you can read the message and put it in the text box like this:

```
outputTextArea.AppendText((e.UserState as string) + "\r\n");
```

This is a bit inefficient, but it should be much safer and faster than your original solution anyway.

In .NET, you've got many options of passing data between threads. If you want to learn more about the concepts, problems and solutions of multi-threading, you can give this a go: http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: Wow, thanks! I read that the backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged could only send some integer. Damn, so much time lost...

Answer (score 2):

This is not the best way as mentioned in other answers, but it still can work successfully.

You can open a file for reading/writing without blocking other reads/writes. Just use `File.Open` instead of helper methods and provide additional parameters (`FileMode` and `FileShare`)
Here is a complete example. Note that one thread keeps file opened for writing and second thread opens and closes file every time and reads all lines:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string fileName = "c:\\_data\\temp.txt";

            Task writer = new Task(() => {

                using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.Millisecond.ToString());
                        sw.Flush();
                        Thread.Sleep(500);
                    }
                }


            });

            Task reader = new Task(() => {
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    Console.WriteLine("Read again");
                    if (File.Exists(fileName))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs))
                        {
                            while (!r.EndOfStream)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(r.ReadLine());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            writer.Start();
            reader.Start();

            writer.Wait();
            reader.Wait();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Standard Output of processes using System.Diagnostics.Process StandardOutput property (it's a Stream).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Yep i used this in my code, but the problem with the standardOutput is that it can't  dynamically display messages. you have to wait for the end of stream to be able to display anything. And that's the problem i'm trying to overcome.

Comment: If you use a StreamReader and read it line by line, you don't neet to read until the end. You can see the progress while the background process is being executed.

Comment: The problem here is that the only way to report a string to the GUI thread is through the backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted method, thus using the e.Result of the backgroundworker. Therefore, i can't directly use the standardoutput to refresh my GUI.

Comment: @Raizyl You can use the `BackgroundWorker.ReportProgress` method or `Control.Invoke` for example. There's nothing forcing you to only ever communicate when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Windows Communications Foundation to do this.

Following is a complete example.

There are two helper classes that you would normally put into a class library for reuse, `class WcfServiceHost<T>` and `class WcfServiceProxy<T>`.

This is a console app which you should run from the command line twice, passing a parameter of `monitor` for the first instance you start, and `worker` for the second instance.

Run it from the command like like this (assuming the app is called `ConsoleApp1.exe`):

```
start ConsoleApp1.exe monitor
start ConsoleApp1.exe worker
```

and then look at the output. The `monitor` instance is waiting for progress reports from the worker. The `worker` instance is reporting the progress, effectively by calling a function in the `monitor` instance (RPC, or Remote Procedure Call).

Here's the complete code. You will need to reference `System.ServiceModel`:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Threading;


namespace Demo
{
    [ServiceContract]

    interface IProgressReporter
    {
        [OperationContract]

        void ReportProgress(double percentComplete, string message);
    }

    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode=InstanceContextMode.Single)]

    sealed class Monitor: IProgressReporter
    {
        public void ReportProgress(double percentComplete, string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Monitor received progress - Completed {0}%: {1}", percentComplete, message);

            if (percentComplete == 100)
            {
                Program.ReportFinished();
            }
        }
    }

    public sealed class WcfServiceHost<T>: IDisposable where T: class
    {
        public WcfServiceHost(T service, string wcfEndpointAddress)
        {
            _service = service;
            _wcfEndpointAddress = wcfEndpointAddress;

            var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service);

            serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(T), new NetNamedPipeBinding(), wcfEndpointAddress);
            serviceHost.Open();

            _serviceHost = serviceHost;
        }

        public T Service
        {
            get
            {
                return _service;
            }
        }

        public string WcfEndpointAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return _wcfEndpointAddress;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Disposal.</summary>

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_serviceHost != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    _serviceHost.Close();
                }

                catch (Exception exception) // Don't allow exceptions to escape from Dispose().
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("There was an exception while closing the host: " + exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }


        private readonly T _service;
        private readonly string _wcfEndpointAddress;
        private readonly ServiceHost _serviceHost;
    }

    public sealed class WcfServiceProxy<T>: IDisposable where T: class
    {
        public WcfServiceProxy(string wcfEndpointAddress)
        {
            _wcfEndpointAddress = wcfEndpointAddress;
            _channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<T>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(), _wcfEndpointAddress);
            _service = _channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            _comms = _service as ICommunicationObject;

            if (_comms == null)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("proxy does not implement ICommunicationObject.");
            }
        }

        public T Service
        {
            get
            {
                return _service;
            }
        }

        public string WcfEndpointAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return _wcfEndpointAddress;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            closeComms();
            closeChannelFactory();
        }

        private void closeComms()
        {
            try
            {
                _comms.Close();
            }

            catch (CommunicationException exception) // Not closed - call Abort to transition to the closed state.
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CommunicationException while closing ICommunicationObject: " + exception.Message);
                _comms.Abort();
            }

            catch (TimeoutException exception) // Not closed - call Abort to transition to the closed state.
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("TimeoutException while closing ICommunicationObject: " + exception.Message);
                _comms.Abort();
            }

            catch (Exception exception) // Not closed - call Abort to transition to the closed state.
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected exception while closing ICommunicationObject: " + exception.Message);
                _comms.Abort();
            }
        }

        private void closeChannelFactory()
        {
            try
            {
                _channelFactory.Close();
            }

            catch (CommunicationException exception) // Not closed - call Abort to transition to the closed state.
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("CommunicationException while closing ChannelFactory: " + exception.Message);
                _channelFactory.Abort();
            }

            catch (TimeoutException exception) // Not closed - call Abort to transition to the closed state.
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("TimeoutException while closing ChannelFactory: " + exception.Message);
                _channelFactory.Abort();
            }

            catch (Exception exception) // Not closed - call Abort to transition to the closed state.
            {
                Trace.WriteLine("Unexpected exception while closing ChannelFactory: " + exception.Message);
                _channelFactory.Abort();
            }
        }

        private readonly T _service;
        private readonly string _wcfEndpointAddress;
        private readonly ChannelFactory<T> _channelFactory;
        private readonly ICommunicationObject _comms;
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "worker")
                runWorker();
            else
                runMonitor();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnded. Press a key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void ReportFinished()
        {
            finished.Set();
        }

        static void runMonitor()
        {
            using (new WcfServiceHost<IProgressReporter>(new Monitor(), SERVICE_PIPE_NAME))
            {
                finished.WaitOne();
            }
        }

        static void runWorker()
        {
            using (var proxy = new WcfServiceProxy<IProgressReporter>(SERVICE_PIPE_NAME))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; ++i)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                    Console.WriteLine("Worker reporting progress: Completed {0}%: {1}", i, i);
                    proxy.Service.ReportProgress(i, i.ToString());
                }
            }
        }

        private static ManualResetEvent finished = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        private const string SERVICE_PIPE_NAME = "net.pipe://localhost/MyServicePipeName";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it sounds promising, but i don't get what the things between [] means ([ServiceContract] ...) and the reference to serviceModel can't be found.
Do you have a link to the site which provide this demo ? i would like to understand all the process and some things i don't know yet (such as the "sealed" property of a class.

Comment: I wrote this demo myself. `[ServiceContract]` is defined in `System.ServiceModel.dll` (a standard .Net assembly) - did you add a reference to that? I mention the need to do so in my answer.

Comment: Here's documentation for `sealed`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/88c54tsw.aspx

Comment: @Raizyl Here's the Microsoft documentation for WCF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx It's rather a lot more than you need for what you want to do - you should just be able to modify my sample code a bit. If you run it, you can see what happens and then try to follow how it works.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to you i managed to do what i wanted ^^
Since it took me quite some time to search/debug, I share my solution.

I used a temporary text file, so it's not very "professional" but it works.

To run the process, you have to call :

```
string[] args = { "/c cmd1", "cmd2" , "cmd3"};
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(args);
```

(sync on a button pressed event for example)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string fileName = "c:\\temp\\tempoutput.txt";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler
                (backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);

    }

    void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This function fires on the UI thread so it's safe to edit the UI control directly

        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        readTempFile();
        //outputTextArea.Text = "Processing......" + progressBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
    }



    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // command line
        string[] args = e.Argument as string[];
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(2);

        try
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
            sw.WriteLine("### Starting the process : ###");
            sw.Flush();

            System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "WorkdirPath";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";

            // create the command line
            int nArgs = args.Length;
            if (nArgs > 0)
            {
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = args[0];
            }
            for (int i = 1; i < nArgs; i++)
            {
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Concat(process.StartInfo.Arguments, " && ", args[i]);
            }

            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(5);
            process.Start();
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10);

            System.IO.StreamWriter sIn = process.StandardInput;
            System.IO.StreamReader sOut = process.StandardOutput;
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(15);

            int timeCount = 15;
            string tempOut = "";

            while (!sOut.EndOfStream)
            {
                tempOut = sOut.ReadLine();
                sw.WriteLine(tempOut);
                sw.Flush();
                if (timeCount < 90)
                {
                    // increasing the progress bar value.
                    //timeCount += 1;
                }
                backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(timeCount);
            }

            sw.WriteLine("Closing process");
            sw.Flush();
            process.Close();
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(100);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException exept)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exept.Message);
            return;
        } 
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        readTempFile();
    }


    private void readTempFile()
    {
        try
        {
            FileStream fs = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(fs);
            string output = r.ReadToEnd();
            outputTextArea.Text = output;
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException exept)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exept.Message);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not redirect `StandardError` if you're not reading it. If the application actually starts writing something in there, you're going to freeze both the applications when the buffer gets full. And why are you using a *file* to communicate between two threads? Are you a PHP / Linux programmer per-chance? You can simply use thread-safe shared memory instead. Using a temporary file to communicate between two threads in one process is just plain silly. And of course, there's no need to run the command line process in a background worker anyway - just read the `StandardOutput` asynchronously.

Comment: Indeed i am a Linux programmer ^^ How can you read the standardOutput asynchronously since the UI can't communicate with the output of the backgroundworker ? Do you have any exemple of thread-safe shared memory ? What is the better way to do what I want according to you ?